# Ctrl-click/Right-click to open in new tab not working in Angular4 (click) event

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a `<a>` tag which has a `(click)` event calling a function. Left clicking on this works normally, but if I want to middle click, ctrl-click, or right click to open in new tab It doesn't work at all. I have also tried using `[routerLink]="foo()"`, but the method gets called multiple times without without even needing to trigger the event, which is not what I want to happen, I want to call the function when I click it. Thanks.

Comment: u have to distinguish click event as by click event you mean all the clicks be it left or right. some think like [this](https://github.com/msarsha/ng2-right-click-menu) will help

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh but I need to do this natively. Capturing the event would work fine with the ctrl-click, but not for right click context menu or middle click.

Comment: Is it not working when you deploy ? or also in localhost?

Comment: @Wandrille both deploy and localhost. The left click works fine, its just I need the right click context menu for opening in new tab

Comment: @SinaH ah ok, I don't know why. I though you had an other issue. Sorry.